# Why is this thrown object not caught when using link-time optimization?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a function in a shared library throwing some object, and a main executable calling that function and attempting to catch that object, e.g.

#### decl.h

```
#ifndef DECL_H
#define DECL_H

void pitch();

struct MyException {
    MyException();
    MyException(const MyException&);
    ~MyException();
};

#endif
```

#### pitch.cpp

```
#include "decl.h"

MyException::MyException() {}
MyException::MyException(const MyException&) {}
MyException::~MyException() {}


void pitch() {
    throw MyException();
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "decl.h"

int main() {
    try { pitch(); }
    catch (MyException& e) { printf("MyException()\n"); }
    catch (...)            { printf("[unknown exception]\n"); }
}
```

#### Makefile

```
all:
    $(CXX) -shared -fPIC $(CXXFLAGS) $(LTO) pitch.cpp -o libpitch.so
    $(CXX) -g $(CXXFLAGS) $(LTO) main.cpp -L. -lpitch
    ./a.out
```

If I compile without link-time optimization, all is well:

```sh
CXXFLAGS="-g -O2" LTO=""      make
c++ -shared -fPIC -g -O2  pitch.cpp -o libpitch.so
c++ -g -g -O2  main.cpp -L. -lpitch
./a.out
MyException()
```

But once I turn on link-time optimization, the thrown object is no longer caught:

```sh
CXXFLAGS="-g -O2" LTO="-flto" make
c++ -shared -fPIC -g -O2 -flto pitch.cpp -o libpitch.so
c++ -g -g -O2 -flto main.cpp -L. -lpitch
./a.out
[unknown exception]
```

Is this expected behavior? Is this a problem in my C++ code, or something else? This is on macOS 10.14.5:

```sh
$ c++ -v
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not expected behavior.

I tested it on linux (ubuntu) with gcc 4.x, 5.x, 6.x, 7.x and 8.x and with clang 6.0. All work just fine with `-O2 -flto`.

Unfortunately, since I cannot reproduce it (I don't have a Mac) I can't tell you what is wrong, but it isn't your code imho.

EDIT:

I can't in good conscious say there is "nothing wrong" with your code (although I tested it as shown by you - HOWEVER, I needed to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="."` for `./a.out` to work (so perhaps you are loading some other library?)) without showing you how I'd write the above code:

//decl.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <exception>

void pitch();

struct MyException : public std::exception
{
};
```

//pitch.cpp:

```
#include "decl.h"

void pitch()
{
  throw MyException();
}
```

// main.cpp:

```
#include "decl.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  try
  {
    pitch();
  }
  catch (MyException const& e)
  {
    std::cout << "MyException(): " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    std::cerr << "[unknown exception]" << std::endl;
  }
}
```